# Force max length for string in PostgreSQL

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I am using heroku for a RoR application and am trying to manually set the length of a string column and am having trouble.

I tried making a migration along the lines of

```
change_column :posts, :content, :string, :length => 10000
```

I assumed this would work but no such luck, anyone have some pointers?

Thanks!

Answer (score 93, accepted):

The length limit option in Rails migrations is called `:limit`:

```
change_column :posts, :content, :string, :limit => 10000
```

If you are finding yourself changing `VARCHAR` length limits a lot, you might want to read @depesz's blog post on [`VARCHAR` vs `TEXT`](http://www.depesz.com/index.php/2010/03/02/charx-vs-varcharx-vs-varchar-vs-text/).